# Exclude lines if ref and grade match in another sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

It is the first time I am using Google sheet and I need to sort tables from two differents sheets.
I want to keep only the **ref** that don't have a **grade** of A

here is a link in google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1quXkNuSYPF7MCs7_PGzjHKOLDf0TSvPqlEumNCWc0lc/edit?usp=sharing

**February '22**

[image: February '22]

**March '22**

[image: March'22]

**Expected result (comparison between Feb and March)**

[image: Comparison]

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you share a worksheet example? - are you using formulas or google apps script? - one idea I have is to add a new column and filter that column by values that does NOT have the value "A" on the B column...

Comment: I did a google sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1quXkNuSYPF7MCs7_PGzjHKOLDf0TSvPqlEumNCWc0lc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: it is public now  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({'February''22'!A:B; 'March''22'!A2:B}; 
 "where Col2 <> 'A' and Col2 is not null"; 1)
```

or if you want only uniques:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({'February''22'!A:B; 'March''22'!A2:B}; 
 "where Col2 <> 'A' and Col2 is not null"; 1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, it's not working , you can edit the sheet if you wanna try

Comment: @marie answer and your sheet updated

Comment: @marie being fair, I think player0's answer is better :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternative:

- In a new sheet, use "QUERY" for get all the data from the columns you desired to manipulate - *see example # 1*.
- Create a new column "called **FILTER**" - in the "C" column which will have this formula - *see example # 2*.
- Add an filter on this new sheet and filter the "C" column for filter those values with value `1`.
- *Optional*: you can hide the "**FILTER**" (*which is the "C" column*) by clicking the "C" column header > choose "hide column".

You can see the results in the "**`Feuille 4`**" sheet in your google sheet sample.

Example # 1:

*Get all data from the (February'22) at the "A" column - in the ranges: A2:A7*

```
=QUERY('February''22'!A2:A7)
```

Example # 2:

*Add value **`0`** when the value in the cells of the column "B" is equals to "A" - otherwise: **`1`***

```
=IF(B2 = "A";0;1)
```

Comment: Great ! Shall I open a new question? I forgot to ask to remove the same occurrences...

Comment: @marie probably, but, before that, search first and if you don't get any results, then, post a new question :) - tip: you can remove duplicates by selecting "data > data cleaning > remove duplicates"